# Operator inequality for selfadjoint operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $0\leq A \leq \mathbb{I}$ and $0\leq B \leq \mathbb{I}$ be two positive operators. Is the following true:

\begin{equation}
(A+B)^x \leq A^x + B^x,
\end{equation}
where $x \in (0,1)$.

For two selfadjoint operators $A$ and $B$ we say that $A \leq B$, if $(B-A)$ is a positive operator.